# Getting Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."

Tags: iphone, .net, ios, nsurlconnection

i calling web service from my ios app using NSURLConnection. here is my code

```
#define kBaseServerUrl       @"http://winshark.softwaytechnologies.com/bariodwcfservice/baroidservice.svc/Json/"

#define kProductServiceUrl @"Products"

-(void)callService{
    NSURL *url;
    if (currState == ProductServiceState) {
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%d",kBaseServerUrl,kProductServiceUrl,[self getRevisionNumberForProduct]]];
    }
    else if(currState == TankStrickerServiceState){
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%d",kBaseServerUrl,kTankStrickerServiceUrl,[self getRevisionNumberForTankStricker]]];
    }else if(currState == CalculationServiceState){
        url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%d",kBaseServerUrl,kCalculationServiceUrl,[self getRevisionNumberForCalculation]]];
    }else{
        //Future Use
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[url absoluteString]);
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSURLConnection *urlConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];

    NSLog(@"%@",urlConnection);
}
```

Its end up calling this url http://winshark.softwaytechnologies.com/bariodwcfservice/baroidservice.svc/Json/Products/123

but when i hit this url in browser its working fine, but in my app i m getting this error

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server."
```

Please help me what might be problem

Comment: Are you testing this on the device or on simulator?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are setting it up right, I would suspect something regarding your objects - try calling a hard coded URL by replacing your existing URL request with:

```
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest 
requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Should make troubleshooting this much easier.

Comment: it's weird, I can't find `requestWithString` method in [NSURLRequest class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) ... can you help me please?

Comment: I think the best help I can give you is point you to some good other SO code ;-) check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19263186/nsurlrequest-creation-using-query-string-in-ios for examples of URL requests made this way.

Comment: @MaxGontar There isn't one. I think he meant `[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"…"]]`.

Comment: @devios thanks, was just going on memory and didn't catch the mismatch