# NSURLRequest creation using query string in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created one user enquiry form in ios. I'm using php as a server side. I constructed query string like bellow in IOS

```
http://www.mydomain.in/androidmail_enquiry.php?name=Vinoth Kumar&phone=04259280244&email=vinoth@ldomain.com&address=Coimbatore&comments=Sample Enquiry&mobile=xxxxxxxx
```

Code:

```
-(void)sendEnquiryDetails
{
    cmttextview.text = @"Sample Enquiry";
    NSString *siteurl = @"http://www.mydomain.in/androidmail_enquiry.php?";
    NSString *name = txtName.text;
    NSString *phone = txtPhone.text;
    NSString *email = txtEmail.text;
    NSString *address = txtAddress.text;
    NSString *comments = cmttextview.text;
    NSString *mobile = txtMobile.text;
    NSString *enquiryurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@name=%@&phone=%@&email=%@&address=%@&comments=%@&mobile=%@",siteurl,name,phone,email,address,comments,mobile];

    NSLog(enquiryurl);

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:enquiryurl]];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request  delegate:self];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    //NSLog(@"didReceiveResponse");
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat :@"didfailwitherror: %@", [error description]]);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading: (NSURLConnection *)connection{
    NSLog(@"Success Code:%@",self.responseData);
}
```

But when i submit this by using NSURLRequest getting error like invalid url(URL Forming error) in didFailWithError method.

Comment: post your code what you did...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure You have added **stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding** , because in your url there is space in name , so in browser it is replaced with %20 you have to add  programmatically in code,

Try this

```
-(void)sendEnquiryDetails
{
    cmttextview.text = @"Sample Enquiry";
    NSString *siteurl = @"http://www.mydomain.in/androidmail_enquiry.php?";
    NSString *name = txtName.text;
    NSString *phone = txtPhone.text;
    NSString *email = txtEmail.text;
    NSString *address = txtAddress.text;
    NSString *comments = cmttextview.text;
    NSString *mobile = txtMobile.text;
    NSString *enquiryurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@name=%@&phone=%@&email=%@&address=%@&comments=%@&mobile=%@",siteurl,name,phone,email,address,comments,mobile];

    NSLog(enquiryurl);

 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[enquiryurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request  delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: Thanks i corrected my mistake, now it's working by added stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding

Comment: @VinothKumar This only works if the password (and any of the other fields) do not contain any of the other reserved characters (e.g. `&`, `+` and others). You should use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` if you want this to be more robust.

Answer (score 4):

You have to percent escape reserved characters. If nothing else, you have to replace those spaces with `+` (or `%20`).

Unfortunately, the standard `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` is not up to the job, as it leaves some characters unescaped. Your sample doesn't include any of them, but if the person's name was entered as "Bill & Melinda Gates" or "Bill + Melinda Gates", `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` would not handle that properly. You really should use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` to percent escape the values, for example using this category:

```
@implementation NSString (URLEncode)

- (NSString *)stringForHTTPRequest
{
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@" ",
                                                                                 (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                                 kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}

@end
```

This properly escapes all reserved characters, but replaces spaces with `+` characters (which you should do if your request type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`).

Alternatively, you can also replace the space characters with `%20` like so:

```
- (NSString *)stringForHTTPRequest
{
    return CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                     NULL,
                                                                     (CFStringRef)@":/?@!$&'()*+,;=",
                                                                     kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
}
```

With that, you could modify that line of code that builds the URL string:

```
NSString *enquiryurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@name=%@&phone=%@&email=%@&address=%@&comments=%@&mobile=%@",
                        siteurl, 
                        [name stringForHTTPRequest],
                        [phone stringForHTTPRequest],
                        [email stringForHTTPRequest],
                        [address stringForHTTPRequest],
                        [comments stringForHTTPRequest],
                        [mobile stringForHTTPRequest]];
```

Comment: Finally, I can agree with most of your statements. :) The "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding algorithm *can* be implemented using `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` and `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:` the way you suggested, just with a slightly *different* set of `legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped`. But eventually, after decoding, both resulting strings are equal again anyway. I will edit may answer and remove the other irrelevant stuff.

Comment: @Rob AFNetworking converts the characters `:/?&=;+!@#$()',*` are you missing some \?

Comment: @DavidCaunt Yes, that is correct. That escapes all of the reserved characters listed in RFC 3986 (though the `#` is not needed, because that's already escaped). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: What's about the `*` which is element of the `sub-delims` set? According RFC 3986, in a query component, characters from the `sub-delims` set don't need to be encoded. The "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" does also not require to encode it. :)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I agree that you might not have to escape the `sub-delim`, but I see no reason not to, and it seems more future-proof to include it. I don't know why you'd escape some of the `sub-delim`, but single out the asterisk for exclusion. If this still troubles you, I'd suggest you ask a new S.O. question on the topic, or submit an [issue to AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues) and ask there. But the convention of AFNetworking (which I've adopted here) is to escape all of the RFC3986 reserved characters.

Comment: Well, regarding "x-www-form-urlencoded", I want to be as close as possible to the w3c recommendation draft, which is by the way up to date: the suggested algorithm is from August, 2013. The RFC 3986 is from January 2005. I don't know what to do in this case, since the w3c algorithm is defined for _forms_, not for _URLs_, but nonetheless is in wide spread use for encoding of the query component. I think the best what we can get are _opinions_ of what might be the best solution. And lastly, it doesn't matter anyway - except perhaps for some unwary decoder.

Comment: Yeah, don't use RFC 3986. Go with spec W3C: HTML5 Forms: URL-encoded form data: application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm. For a swift implementation, see [application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm Swift iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26317562/242933).

Answer (score 2):

According the docs, if a `NSURL` object is initialized with a string, the string must conform to [RFC 2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) (see official Apple docs [URLWithString](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/URLWithString:)).

The most recent RFC however is [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) which obsoletes RFC 2396.

#### Caution:

**Neither Cocoa nor Core Foundation will have a function which out of the box returns a properly encoded URL string conforming to RFC 2396 or RFC 3986, though.**

**Different components of a URL have varying percent encoding requirements.**

Edit:

In order to transmit *structured* parameters in a unstructured query component of a URL, an encoding scheme equal to the [application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#application/x-www-form-urlencoded-encoding-algorithm) *can* be applied to the query component.

A helper function which encodes the *name* or *value* and which conforms to that encoding can be implemented as:

```
static NSString* urlformdata_encode(NSString* s) {
    CFStringRef charactersToLeaveUnescaped = CFSTR(" ");
    CFStringRef legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped = CFSTR("!$&'()+,/:;=?@~");
    
    NSString *result = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                             kCFAllocatorDefault,
                             (__bridge CFStringRef)s,
                             charactersToLeaveUnescaped,
                             legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped,
                             kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
    return [result stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];
}
```

(Note: this code depends on the current implementation of `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, especially its default escaping. If those change, the code may not correctly implement the algorithm.)

According RFC 3986, the `query` component of the URL is treated as an *unstructured* percent encoded byte stream containing only ASCII characters.

Originally, the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding scheme has been defined for transmitting form-data from a browser to a server which becomes the payload of a body. That is, the context is totally different than for URLs. Nonetheless, even this encoding scheme is not defined in RFC 3986, it is finally compatible with the URL encoding scheme.

#### Caveats

The "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding scheme may produce percent escapes for characters that are now in the "Unreserved" character set according RFC 3986, namely the tilde `~` character. Characters in the "Unreserved" character set don't need to be escaped.
More strictly, due to implications in URI comparison implementations, RFC 3986 makes this recommendation:

*"For consistency, percent-encoded octets in the ranges of ALPHA (%41-%5A and %61-%7A), DIGIT (%30-%39), hyphen (%2D), period (%2E), underscore (%5F), or tilde (%7E) should not be created by URI producers"*.

In order to *not* escape the tilde `~` in query parameters, one can remove the tilde `~` from the set of legal URL characters to be escaped `legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped`:

```
CFStringRef legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped = CFSTR("!$&'()+,/:;=?@");
```

Not escaping the tilde *should not* cause issues, even though it is not strict according the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoding" algorithm.

#### Differences to the other suggested algorithms to this question:

Since the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" decoding algorithm decodes any percent decoded character sequence into its corresponding Unicode code unit, differences in the set of `legalURLCharactersToBeEscaped` specified in `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` during encoding *may* eventually yield equal strings.

(Edit: removed helper functions which encode components of a URL, which are not relevant when a *query string* should be encoded via *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*)

Comment: We should probably not use that ancient "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoding in URL params. It's perfectly valid to use JSON for example, and percent encode that according a query component defined in RFC 3986.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for hint about the tilde! Added a "Caveat" section explaining the issue.