# Why do I receive "connectionFailed unrecognized selector" with NSURLConnection?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I was trying to post data with a `NSURLConnection`. This is my code:

```
responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

self.regData=data;

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&regId=%@unique_id=%@",self.regData.name,self.regData.email,self.regData.regId,UNIQUE_ID];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:url ];
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
[req setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[req setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[req setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[req setHTTPBody:postData];
(void)[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
```

But, I received an exception like this

```
 NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MAAppDelegate connectionFailed]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15d8b310'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30fbaf53 0x3b2e46af 0x30fbe8e7 0x30fbd071 0x30f0c598 0x19cb83 0x318f43a3 0x318f42e7    0x318f5031 0x319804fd 0x30c280ef 0x30c26ae3 0x30c5831f 0x30eee719 0x30bbec3d 0x30bbeb0d 0x30bbe9a1 0x30f8618b 0x30f8565b 0x30f83e4f 0x30eeece7 0x30eeeacb 0x35bc7283 0x33790a41 0x187dbd 0x3b7ecab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Help me solve this please.

Comment: Your title says "post JSON", but your code says "post x-www-form-urlencoded". Which is it? Also, have you implemented the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods in this object (which I'm gathering is being done in your app delegate)?

Comment: Looks like you're doing this in `MAAppDelegate` which is also set as the delegate of `NSURLConnection`. Try implementing a delegate method `connectionFailed` to see more details. And then you will encounter higher level problems that Rob is talking about.

Comment: actually am using json. i got this stuff from net. and also i successfuly used this for send data... any how could you help me with this code.. if u dnt mind pls...

Comment: is that.. am not much familiar with that.. all i want to post my data to the api... its better if i get help with his code....:-(

Comment: No problem. I've updated title and text of your question to eliminate confusion for future readers, the exception has nothing to do with JSON (nor does the code sample).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Your error message would appear to be unrelated to your code sample, but rather reporting that you tried to call a method called `connectionFailed` for your app delegate. I presume you have some code that tries to call a method by that name. You should update your question to include that code.
2. You might want to [add an exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) so it will identify the line of code that is causing this exception. That may simplify your diagnosis of the problem.
3. As an aside, you are missing an ampersand before `unique_id` in your `POST` data, so this request won't work, even after you fix the above issue.
4. You really should be percent escaping the parameters to your `POST` data. Maybe you don't have any characters that need escaping in your data, but to be safe, you really should be calling `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` to percent escape your data. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19263420/1271826) for an example `NSString` category that you can call to properly percent escape your data.

Comment: actually  i wrote those codes in delegate method of appdelegate. i moved my code to some where else. now there is no exception. thank u very much.... i really mean it...

Comment: and also,i used these method for submitting data in my project. that works perfectly.. i never used percent escapes... some how it works.....

Comment: @MusadhikhMuhammedK Yes, it will work until you encounter some special characters in one of those four fields. For example, if the `name` (or any of these fields) ever had an ampersand or plus sign it it, this existing code might not work. It's just a precaution that one should adopt in case a user enters in any special characters in their input.

Comment: @MusadhikhMuhammedK No, I was warning you about the ampersand, `&`. So, if the user's name was "Bill & Kate", the ampersand would be misinterpreted as prematurely terminating the field. Or, if it was "Bill + Kate", that `+` would be misinterpreted by your server as a space. Thus, when issuing requests that include any input provided by the user, you should generally go through a process of percent escaping with `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`, which will, amongst other things, will replace the `&` with `%26`. Your server will automatically convert this back for you.